# typescript syntax: { new (): T } | { new (): T }[]

Tags: typescript, methods, types, constructor

I was looking through the Vue api docs and noticed some Typescript syntax that doesn't make sense to me

```
type PropType<T> = { new (): T } | { new (): T }[]
```

Is `{ new (): T }` an Object with a constructor method that returns the generic type T, is that what this means?

Comment: It's something that if you call `new thing()` you'll get a T.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an union between two construct signatures:

```js
type PropType<T> = { new (): T } | { new (): T }[]

class A {}

const b = (a: PropType<A>) =>
  a instanceof Array ? [] : new a();
```

Because it is a union this needs type narrowing so the compiler can pluck the right type.

Comment: Does the second union type { new (): T }[] mean it could be an array of objects with constructor methods?

Comment: Yes, union between a single object or a list of objects of the same type